# Showing another progress dialog in onPostExecute of asyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

How to show another `ProgressDialog` in `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask`.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setMessage("Retrieving User Banks...");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
   pd.dismiss();
   ...
}
```

How to add another progress dialog in `onPostExecute` method?

I want to show another progress dialog in `onPostExecute`.

I tried the following code :-

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage("Progess...");
progressDialog.show();



// After task is done.

progressDialog.dismiss();
```

But it does not seem to work. Please throw some insight into this.

Note : You can safely assume that my task is to sort some results that I got from the network call and populate a list, I don't want the UI to be blank till this operation completes. So I want to show a progress dialog to the user.

Comment: Same time to show and hide? is it?

Comment: Yes, because both are for different purposes.

You can safely assume I am sorting the t and the sorting is taking too much time, and after sorting I want to populate a list, but I dont want the UI to be blank till the operation finishes.

Comment: Instead of showing a different `ProgressDialog`, why not update the title or message of the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to reuse the same progress dialog. what i suggest you to do is to use onProgressUpdate() method of asyncTask this method works on main thread so you can update your progress dialog using this method just call publishProgress(param) method from doInbackground. For example.

Suppose i have two web services one is for fetching categories and other for fetching the sub categories. So if i am doing this i will use async task only one progress dialog and what i will do is to update the message of progress dialog every time.

```
onPreExecute()
{

ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
progressDialog.show();
}
doInBackground()
{

// call webservice for fetching category

publishProgress("Loading categories");

// parse webservice result

// call webservice for fetching sub category

publishProgress("Loading Sub categories");

// parse webservice result

} 
onProgressUpdate(String[] args)
{

progressDialog.setMessage(args[0]);
}


onPostExecute()
{
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had got same problem. I solved this link. [Good Luck :D](https://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/dialog/android-badtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-is-your-activity-running/)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LongTask task;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    task = new LongTask(this);
    task.execute((Void) null);

    //finish();
}

private static class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakRef;
    //Activity activity;


    public LongTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        super();
        this.mainActivityWeakRef = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(mainActivity);
        //this.activity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        }
        return "Hello";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("onpostexecute", (mainActivityWeakRef.get() != null) + "");
        if (mainActivityWeakRef.get() != null && !mainActivityWeakRef.get().isFinishing()) {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivityWeakRef.get()).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle(result);
            alertDialog.setMessage("On post execute");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}